# hyphenation of compound adjectives

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

Proofreading a friend's work, I came across the following phrase:

> [teachers and students] work collaboratively to change long held, potentially incorrect and deeply believed views

Now, while I'm sure that in suggesting hyphenation for "long-held" and "deeply-believed" I'd be correct, for a reason I can't quite put my finger on I don't think hyphenating "potentially incorrect" would be appropriate.  Am I correct, and if so, what distinguishes this phrase from the others?

Comment: The *Chicago Manual of Style* has a free 10-page **pdf** that covers hyphenation. You can find it by googling *cmos hyphenation guide*. See also the Related Questions here at ELU.

Comment: Duplicate of [adverb-adjective compound premodifier – with or without hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64755/adverb-adjective-compound-premodifier-with-or-without-hyphen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed), 7.86:

> Compounds formed by an adverb ending in *ly* plus an adjective or participle (such as *largely irrelevant* or *smartly dressed*) are not hyphenated either before or after a noun, since ambiguity is virtually impossible. (The *ly* ending with adverbs signals to the reader that the next word will be another modifier, not a noun.)

While this is not the only style guide there is, this particular piece of advice is quite common.

Therefore, neither *potentially* nor *deeply* would be hyphenated:

> [Teachers and students] work collaboratively to change long-held, potentially incorrect and deeply believed views.

Comment: AP Style agrees.