# Compound adjective hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

In the following sentence:

> Directly substituting all continuous-time components of X by their previously described discrete-time counterparts results in Y because/as [...]

I'm unsure if "previously described discrete-time" should be hyphenated the way it is. According [to this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457717/hyphenation-of-compound-adjectives) any words ending with "ly" are usually not hyphenated so I think "previously described" is correct.

My gut felling is that "previously described discrete-time" is correct, but I'm unsure if it should instead be "previously described-discrete-time" according to the examples of compound adjectives with more than two words that I've seen.

The reason I'm unsure is that if instead of "previously" I used something that doesn't end with "ly", for instance "well", the hyphenation would become "well-described-discrete-time"... right? So does the "no hyphenation" rule for words ending with "ly" affect the hyphenation of the following adjectives? If not (which I don't think it does), then what is the correct hyphenation for this sentence?

I don't think this is a duplicate question as I couldn't find other similar questions, but please do correct me if I'm wrong.