# Are multiple hyphenations allowed in extending compound words like "well-controlled"?

Tags: hyphenation, compounds, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

It is common to write the phrase "well controlled" as a single, hyphenated adjective, "well-controlled".

If my intention is to place additional adverbs in front of the hyphenated compound word "well-controlled", should I expand this compound word with additional hyphenations, i.e. are the compound words "very-well-controlled", or "not-very-well-controlled" correct?

This question doesn't ask about linking two separate compound words as pointed out in the supposedly duplicate question, but rather linking additional adverbs to a single hyphenated compound word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adverb-adjective compound premodifier ... with or without hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64755/adverb-adjective-compound-premodifier-with-or-without-hyphen) Or  [How do I hyphenate an open-form compound word with another that should be hyphenated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-do-i-hyphenate-an-open-form-compound-word-with-another-that-should-be-hyphen) Or [How to hyphenate a phrasal adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/430949/how-to-hyphenate-a-phrasal-adjective-pci-compliant?rq=1)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Neither of the three threads relate to my specific query of expanding an already hyphenated compound word with additional hyphenations.

Comment: How about [doubly-hyphenated words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34583/doubly-hyphenated-words/388709#388709) (though I think there is already advice on hyphenating these compound premodifiers in the threads already mentioned)? I'd probably choose 'well controlled N', 'very well controlled N', and '[an] N that is not very well controlled'.

Comment: I don't see [Is a lengthy combination of words with hyphens like “the worst not-technically-in-a-recession year in American history” a new fashion of writing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84296/) in the above links. But the first example queried there is ***“not-technically–in-a-recession”***, which looks structurally and semantically similar to OP's example ***"not-very-well-controlled"*** here (quirky / facetious negating of a state definition).